# Kotlin, TextView takes a long text from a variable and displays it on the screen WITHOUT SPACES

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function that prints a rhombus and saves it to a variable after which the variable is passed to TextView for display on the screen, everything is output correctly, but for some reason spaces are not output, although they are in the variable that TextView receives.

Unfortunately I am not a native English speaker so this is a machine translation of my problem (

[The variable "logic"/"res" contains the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htKsl.png)

[I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/688Bc.png)

My function:

```
fun printDiamond(n: Int): String {

    for (i in -n..n) {
        for (j in -n - 1..n + 1)
            if (j == 0) {
                str = res
                res = str
            }
            else if (abs(j) == n + 1)
                if (abs(i) == n){
                    str = "$res+"
                    res = str
                }
                else{
                    str = "$res|"
                    res = str
                }
            else if (abs(i) == n){
                str = "$res-"
                res = str
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == -n){
                str = "$res<"
                res = str
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == n){
                str = "$res>"
                res = str
            }
            else if (abs(i - j) == n){
                str = "$res\\"
                res = str
            }
            else if (abs(i + j) == n){
                str = "$res/"
                res = str
            }
            else if (abs(i) + abs(j) < n)
                if ((n - i) % 2 != 0){
                    str = "$res="
                    res = str
                }
                else{
                    str = "$res-"
                    res = str
                }
            else{
                str = "$res "
                res = str
            }
        str = "$res\n"
        res = str
    }
    Log.d("Process", "Return =\n$res")
    return res}
```

My output to the screen:

```
selected = dropdown.selectedItem.toString()
logic = com.example.mobile_lab1.Lab1.Process().printDiamond(selected.toInt())
Log.d("Process", "Logic =\n$logic")
textValue.text = selectedtext.text = logic
```

Comment: It looks to me that the spaces are there just fine. It's just that you are using variable-width font. You need to use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: you can ask the same question on [Russian Stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) as it would be difficult for you to understand the answers.